# Generate entities from MySQL table in Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, jpa, mysql-connector, entities

I have downloaded the '**mysql-connector**' from the https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/com/mysql/mysql-connector-j/8.0.33/mysql-connector-j-8.0.33.jar

And added to the Java build path

[image]

---

But when I try to generate entities from table, its empty.

### **How can I add MySQL connection here.**

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

---

eclipse version is **Version: 2023-06 (4.28.0)**